# Object Model Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, webforms

Okay, so the .NET Framework contains a `TransactionScope` that assist in enlisting in transactions for things like databases. However, I can't seem to find something that's simliar for object models.

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application, and when a user clicks the `Export to Excel` link I've created I **add** to the `Response` object on the `HttpContext` an Excel file. This of course takes a number of modifications such as headers and even writing the `byte[]` of the Excel file.

However, if that fails I get a partially emitted response and it's simply broken.

Is there a technology that would allow me to enlist into an object model transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you certainly can *try* to create a resource that registers itself in a transaction here (see the [`ISinglePhaseNotification` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isinglephasenotification.aspx) as well as the [`EnlistVolatile` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149780.aspx) on the [`Transaction` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5c62w6d.aspx), it's not the right approach for what you want to do as it's technically impossible.

Depending on whether or not buffering is enabled in ASP.NET, once you write bytes out to the response, those bytes are sent to the client, *you can't get them back* as the HTTP protocol doesn't have any mechanism to indicate that the client should discard previously sent bytes. (Note: Web services *do* support transactions, but this isn't a web service, and the approach would be different).

That said, what you *could* do is create a transaction on the server side and have *another* object that creates the Excel file handle enlist in a transaction, but that's overkill as well: you've indicated that the response that you want to send *is* the Excel sheet, and nothing else.  There's nothing else to coordinate with, so no transaction is necessary (unless there are other things you haven't indicated).

With that in mind, you can easily have the method that's creating your Excel file write to a byte array in memory/[`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) instance or to the file system, and then, based on whether or not you've succeeded write the stream or fail the response in some other way.

Granted, there's a performance tradeoff here, as you are writing the sheet to an intermediary medium (memory will be faster than the file system, but you have to take into account how large the sheets are and how many of them you're writing) and then to the response, but that's the tradeoff you have to make (regardless of whether or not you did this in a transaction).

A transaction here is overkill and the wrong design choice.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks a lot for helping me get set straight. What I'm going to do is in fact write it to a `MemoryStream` and upon successful completion I will write that to the response.

Comment: @BigM NP, added a paragraph (second to last) about the fact there *will* be a performance trade-off due the intermediary medium, but there's nothing you can do about it.